# How to have a header between navigation items

Tags: html

I want my navigation menu to have 3 links on the left, the logo in the middle, and 3 more links to the right,

This is the first way I have tried:

```
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
        </ul>  
            <h1> portfolio </h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Is this a good way?

Sorry I've never done this before so I just want to make sure I am doing it a good way

Comment: what they said. Just one remark: if you post your html here, don't use `#` for uri placeholders. `#` is a valid target uri by itself, and someone pedantic may come by and start pointing out that all your a's point to the same location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to float your menus and center header:

Html

```
<div id="header">
    <ul class="left">
        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
    </ul>  
    <h1> portfolio </h1>
    <ul class="right">
        <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Css

```
#header h1 { display:block; text-align:center; }
#header .left { float:left; }
#header .right { float:right; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ub3cP/

Answer (score 0):

That would be just fine. Then you would have to use the CSS `float` property to get everything in line.

Answer (score 0):

It's OK, but there's a gotcha to watch out for. You describe it as a navigation menu, and so it is, and I'm assuming that the `<h1>` is a page header. Now, if you were making a HTML5 page, you'd want to mark your navigation menu appropriately with a `<nav>` element. So you might do this:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
    </ul>  
    <h1> portfolio </h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The problem is that this changes the semantics of the `<h1>` element. It would then be the heading of the nav area, not the heading of the page.

To guard against this, it might be better to have the `<h1>` element either before or after the navigation menu in the markup, and move it into the display position between the two `<ul>`s with CSS.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/mJELq/